# cron midnight 00 24 or 00 00?

Tags: cron

My current crontab looks like this:

```
00 00 * * 1-5 "/home/user/script.sh"
```

But it seems like it is not being triggered. All others are triggering fine except the one running at midnight.

What is the proper format for midnight? `00 00` or `00 24`?

Comment: What OS do you use? There are differences between cron implementations. For example, on Debian (and other Linuxes but not all), you can use `@midnight`. Also, is that a typo or are your actually using `home/user/script.sh` not `/home...`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I fixed the path now. I'll check to see if it triggers tonight.

Comment: OK, in that case I'm voting to close since it is unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe `0 0` is the correct specification for midnight (no leading zeros, so in this case no double zero). From man crontab(5):

> ```
>           field          allowed values
>           -----          --------------
>           minute         0-59
>           hour           0-23
>           day of month   1-31
>           month          1-12 (or names, see below)
>           day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
> ```

If this is in the system crontab (i.e. `/etc/crontab`), make sure the field between the time specifications and the command is the user that the command is to be executed as.

Also make sure that the path to your command is fully specified, in the `$PATH`, or makes sense relative to `$HOME`.